# How does Doc2Vec handle documents where the length is less than the window size?

Tags: natural-language, text-mining, word-embeddings, word2vec, doc2vec

I am using doc2vec to vectorise documents that average in length 10 words (PV-DBOW implementation of the algorithm). I am wondering how doc2vec handles cases where the number of words in a document is smaller than the window size? (I am trying to decide between a 5 and 10 word window size at the moment and I'm unsure).